# How can I Refactor my code in laravel OOP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, refactoring

My code is not readable and hard to scale.

```
<?php
namespace App\Services;

use App\Models\BlogCategory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

Class BlogServices
{
    public function getCategoriesByUserAndCompany(int $user_id, array $company_ids): Collection
    {
        return BlogCategory::whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
                $query->where('user_id',$user_id);
            })->orWhereHas('company', function ($query) use ($company_ids) {
                foreach($company_ids as $id) {
                    $query->oRwhere('company_id',$id);
                }

            })->get();
    }
}
```

I need to get all categories that are related to companies and users.
BlogCategory related many to many with User 
BlogCategory related many to many with Company

Sorry for my english, thanks.

---

now

```
<?php
namespace App\Services;

use App\Models\Company;
use App\Models\BlogCategory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;


Class BlogServices
{
    public function getCategoriesByUserAndCompany(int $user_id, array $company_ids): Collection
    {
        $company = $this->getCategoriesByCompany($company_ids);

        return $this->getCategoriesByUser($user_id)->union($company)->get();
    }

    public function getCategoriesByUser(int $user_id)
    {
        return BlogCategory::whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
            $query->where('user_id',$user_id);
        });
    }

    public function getCategoriesByCompany(array $company_ids)
    {
        return BlogCategory::whereHas('company', function ($query) use ($company_ids) {
                $query->whereIn('company_id', $company_ids);
            });       
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your code returning expected results and you just want to refactor? Or your having trouble retrieving the expected results?

Comment: @RobertKujawa The code returns the expected result. But I think that it can be made more readable and expandable, but I don’t know how. May i need use scope ?

Comment: I added an answer below, it should work if you are using Laravel version 5.1 or above.

Comment: @RobertKujawa, thanks, i did not see this mistake.

Comment: @RobertKujawa, What do you think of the new code?

Comment: Truthfully, I believe it follows refactoration standards but, I find it to be "Over engineered'.

Comment: If you wish to query relations based on user filters, you can try chaining the query, I will update my answer to give an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I would refactor is how you check the if the company relation exists. Laravel has a method called `whereIn()`, you can use that instead of looping through your `$company_ids`.

```
<?php
namespace App\Services;

use App\Models\BlogCategory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

Class BlogServices
{
    public function getCategoriesByUserAndCompany(int $user_id, array $company_ids): Collection
    {
        return BlogCategory::whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
                $query->where('user_id',$user_id);
            })->orWhereHas('company', function ($query) use ($company_ids) {
                $query->whereIn('company_id', $company_ids);
            })->get();
    }
}
```

That should be the cleanest way to get the same results. I find it to be very neat.

**Here is an update on how you can filter your query based on user input:**

Instead of making a function for each possible filter you can add to the query, try chaining your query based on the users request.

```
public function getCategories(Request $request): Collection
{
    $categories = BlogCategory::query(); //Initialaze query on BlogCategory

    // Check if user requested categories to be filtered by user.
    $user_id = $request->get('user_id', false); 
    if($user_id) {
        $categories->whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
            $query->where('user_id',$user_id);
        });
    }
    // Check if user requested for categories to be filtered by companies.
    $company_ids = $request->query('company_ids', false); 
    if ($company_ids) {
        $categories->whereHas('company', function ($query) use ($company_ids) {
            $query->whereIn('company_id', $company_ids);
        });
    }

    return $categories->get();
}
```

Comment: Does this violate the Single responsibility principle?

Comment: @alex159 If what you are trying to achieve is filter results directly by user input, I believe not.